# Will HTML5 video source URL follow header redirects?

Tags: video, html, redirect, http-headers

Right now I am still using flash as primary player and have a HTML5 fallback, because its still buggy especially when it comes to codes.

However my question is, if I have a video source in an HTML5 `video` tag,  and the source actually delivers a document (with correct content type headers etc of course) with an header redirect issued to the real video source, will there be any problems with that? I can't find any documentation about that.

Comment: Well, why not test it out? There are enough browsers that support video now. I imagine that an HTTP 30x redirect should work, but delivering an HTML document with a redirect probably won't. That's just a guess though.

Comment: yeah of course i can test it out but i'd like some sort of reference or standard for that...

Comment: The video is fetched over HTTP, so HTTP redirects ought to be respected. Redirect codes in HTML might not. But why not start with what browsers really do? If browsers don't follow the type of redirect you want, then what the standards say is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: well i think thats kinda what i wanted to hear +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5, by the specification, probably every resources - including the resources to be downloaded when using the elements `<script>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, `<video>`, `<audio>`, `<source>`, `<track>` and so on - are obtained by a process described as [**"fetching"**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fetching-resources.html#fetching-resources) which also takes HTTP redirects into account (step 7. of the process in the given link).